# Loading Screen that disappears after click button not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a simple code, but it does not work regularly. I want working  loading image when pressing button also . Now it only works upon first entering the page. loading image works, but when i click on button, it does not work.

```
<form action="2.php" method="post" id="formx">
<div id="onelod" class="spinner-container ng-isolate-scope">
<div class="spinner-block">
<div class="spinner"></div>
<p class="text-center spinner-text">Loading...</p>
</div>
</div>
<button class="btn login-button btn-submit btn-small" type="submit" data-uia="login-submit-button">Sign In</button>

</form>
```

```
document.onreadystatechange = function () {
  var state = document.readyState
  if (state == 'complete') {
      setTimeout(function(){
          document.getElementById('interactive');
         document.getElementById('onelod').style.visibility="hidden";
      },3000);
  }
}
```

```
.spinner {
margin: 10px;
width: 200px;
height: 103px;
background: url(../IMG/lod.gif)
}
```

Comment: where is your code that works on button click

Comment: You don't have an event connected to the button's [`onclick`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick)

Comment: If your going to another page or posting a form, `type="submit"`.. then loading will not be seen, working click event or not

Comment: @VishnuBhadoriya Can you correct the error if possible

Comment: please see @Rojo's answer

Comment: @Rojo do u mean i put onclick() to button ?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone yes i want going to another page what are u mean with this code type="submit" when i put this ?

Comment: [See this w3schools example](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_ev_onclick)

Comment: @Rojo Can you write the code below and correct my mistake if possible?

Comment: @Rojo Did not work, it moved to a second page without loading

Comment: Without loading what? Your question is still unclear, I don't know how I would write code for you. You are saying one thing in the question and another in the comments. I suggest you edit your post and include a lot more information. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Rojo I think that because of the language I could not communicate an idea I apologize for a language because my language is not english.
In any case, my problem, my brother, is when starting a page, he loads a page and shows a loading image, but after filling in information in fields, press the button, and the page does not shows a loading image
 It goes directly to the next page

Comment: @Rojo Hope that idea has arrived to you now.

Comment: Well then you just need to add this loading code to the next page

Comment: @Rojo On the same page, I want it to loading image for 3 seconds, and then it will move to a second page Hope you take a look here so you understand well
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33913074/creating-a-loading-screen-that-disappears-after-x-time-on-button-click

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230087/discussion-between-rojo-and-nikola).

Answer (score 1):

You could create an onsubmit event with event.preventDefault(), show the loading gif, wait 3 seconds, and then fire the submit function.

```js
document.onreadystatechange = function() {
  var state = document.readyState
  if (state == 'complete') {
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById('interactive');
      document.getElementById('onelod').style.visibility = "hidden";
    }, 3000);
  }
}
var formElement = document.getElementById("formx");
formElement.onsubmit = event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  document.getElementById('onelod').style.visibility = "visible";
  setTimeout(() => formElement.submit(), 3000); // You can set the amount of ms to wait
}
```

```css
.spinner {
  margin: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 103px;
  background: url(../IMG/lod.gif)
}
```

```html
<form action="2.php" method="post" id="formx">
  <div id="onelod" class="spinner-container ng-isolate-scope">
    <div class="spinner-block">
      <div class="spinner"></div>
      <p class="text-center spinner-text">Loading...</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="btn login-button btn-submit btn-small" type="submit" data-uia="login-submit-button">Sign In</button>

</form>
```

You can set a different amount of ms to wait.

**Note**: the form will **not** be submitted to the server while the loading gif is being shown.